# re-add to RAID1 is not possible

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, raid, kubuntu, raid-1

On Kubuntu 13.10 I have two hdd: 
sdb 1TB with two partitions - one in RAID1 and second is simple. Second hdd sda 500GB is whole in RAID1. 
Once I unpluged second hdd, put there some other hdd instead, copy somthing from it to sdb and pluged sda back - I know it wasnt great idea, but I was in hurry :) 
Now I want to put sdb back to RAID 
for

> ~# mdadm --detail /dev/md/0

i have

> /dev/md/0: 
>           Version : 1.2 
>     Creation Time : Wed Oct 31 19:03:13 2012 
>        Raid Level : raid1 
>        Array Size : 11709312 (11.17 GiB 11.99 GB) 
>     Used Dev Size : 11709312 (11.17 GiB 11.99 GB) 
>      Raid Devices : 2 
>     Total Devices : 1 
>       Persistence : Superblock is persistent 
>       Update Time : Thu Dec 12 18:25:33 2013 
>             State : clean, degraded 
>   Active Devices : 1 
>   Working Devices : 1 
>    Failed Devices : 0 
>     Spare Devices : 0 
>              Name : zizalak:0  (local to host zizalak)
>              UUID : e7642026:bc8830b1:683d0612:73062736
>            Events : 143789

```
Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   0       0        0        0      removed
   1       8       23        1      active sync   /dev/sdb7
```

so I tried

> mdadm --re-add /dev/md/0 /dev/sda2

but it wrote

> mdadm: --re-add for /dev/sda2 to /dev/md/0 is not possible

thanks for any advice 
________

> dmesg

> [    2.120271] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
>   
>  [    2.124245] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
>   
>  [    2.292377] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
>   
>  [    2.293483] ata1.00: ATA-8: WDC WD5000AAKS-00V1A0, 05.01D05, max UDMA/133
>   
>  [    2.293487] ata1.00: 976773168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
>   
>  [    2.294617] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
>   
>  [    2.294825] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      WDC WD5000AAKS-0 05.0 PQ: 0 
>  ANSI: 5
>   
>  [    2.294972] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/465 GiB)
>   
>  [    2.295003] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
>   
>  [    2.295006] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
>   
>  [    2.295019] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't 
>  support DPO or FUA
>   
>  [    2.295027] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
>   
>  [    2.296377] ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
>   
>  [    2.298126] ata4.00: ATA-8: WDC WD10EALX-009BA0, 15.01H15, max UDMA/133
>   
>  [    2.298130] ata4.00: 1953525168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
>   
>  [    2.299916] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
>   
>  [    2.300103] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      WDC WD10EALX-009 15.0 PQ: 0 
>  ANSI: 5
>   
>  [    2.300276] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
>   
>  [    2.300290] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
>   
>  [    2.300530] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
>   
>  [    2.300533] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
>   
>  [    2.300586] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't 
>  support DPO or FUA
>   
>  [    2.303858] scsi 5:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GH22NS50  TN02 PQ: 0 
>  ANSI: 5
>   
>  [    2.313709] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 48x/48x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
>   
>  [    2.313714] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
>   
>  [    2.313874] sr 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
>   
>  [    2.313996] sr 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
>   
>  [    2.331418]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3
>   
>  [    2.331757] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
>   
>  [    2.348399]  sdb: sdb2 < sdb5 sdb6 sdb7 sdb8 > sdb3 sdb4
>   
>  [    2.349002] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
>   
>  [    2.384447] tsc: Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 2800.115 MHz
>   
>  [    2.474936] md: bind
>   
>  [    2.476572] md: raid1 personality registered for level 1
>   
>  [    2.476863] md/raid1:md1: active with 1 out of 2 mirrors
>   
>  [    2.476880] md1: detected capacity change from 0 to 485963399168
>   
>  [    2.535184] md: bind
>   
>  [    2.843939]  md1: unknown partition table
>   
>  [    3.380755] md: bind
>   
>  [    3.381155] md: kicking non-fresh sda2 from array!
>   
>  [    3.381164] md: unbind
>   
>  [    3.385373] Switched to clocksource tsc
>   
>  [    3.443969] md: export_rdev(sda2)
>   
>  [    3.445108] md/raid1:md0: active with 1 out of 2 mirrors
>   
>  [    3.445131] md0: detected capacity change from 0 to 11990335488
>   
>  [    3.588503]  md0: unknown partition table
>   
>  [    4.469228] md: linear personality registered for level -1
>   
>  [    4.470889] md: multipath personality registered for level -4
>   
>  [    4.472510] md: raid0 personality registered for level 0
>   
>  [    4.542183] raid6: mmxx1     2335 MB/s
>   
>  [    4.610240] raid6: mmxx2     4366 MB/s
>   
>  [    4.678377] raid6: sse1x1     620 MB/s
>   
>  [    4.746379] raid6: sse1x2    1183 MB/s
>   
>  [    4.814406] raid6: sse2x1    1288 MB/s
>   
>  [    4.882477] raid6: sse2x2    2633 MB/s
>   
>  [    4.950516] raid6: int32x1   1173 MB/s
>   
>  [    5.018603] raid6: int32x2   1166 MB/s
>   
>  [    5.086652] raid6: int32x4   1055 MB/s
>   
>  [    5.154707] raid6: int32x8    814 MB/s
>   
>  [    5.154709] raid6: using algorithm mmxx2 (4366 MB/s)
>   
>  [    5.154711] raid6: using intx1 recovery algorithm
>   
>  [    5.155003] xor: measuring software checksum speed
>   
>  [    5.194707]    pIII_sse  : 10899.000 MB/sec
>   
>  [    5.234740]    prefetch64-sse: 11130.000 MB/sec
>   
>  [    5.234742] xor: using function: prefetch64-sse (11130.000 MB/sec)
>   
>  [    5.234902] async_tx: api initialized (async)
>   
>  [    5.235791] md: raid6 personality registered for level 6
>   
>  [    5.235794] md: raid5 personality registered for level 5
>   
>  [    5.235796] md: raid4 personality registered for level 4
>   
>  [    5.240501] md: raid10 personality registered for level 10
>   
>  [    5.489939] EXT4-fs (md0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
>   
>  [   15.685299] Adding 1951740k swap on /dev/sda1.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:1951740k FS
>   [   15.843045] Adding 1952764k swap on /dev/sdb6.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:1952764k FS

Comment: Gimme a dmesg output please.

Comment: there it is :-)

Comment: Did you try adding options `-b -v` (first try) and `-v` (second try) to the `mdadm` command?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the whole problem that you are trying to re-add sba2 instead of sdb7? After all, sda was never removed...

Comment: no no - it was only typo - I already corrected it - sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
[ 2.120271] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[ 2.124245] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[ 2.292377] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
```

I think you should use a bigger/better power.

Comment: You noticed that those are three *different* SATA adapters?

Comment: @U.Windl Yes, but mysterious disconnects-reconnects are happening still mostly on power reason. Funny, my this answer is 7 years old.